# Typescript declarations inside default.d.ts or default.theme.d.ts not working

Tags: typescript

I am using styled-components with typescript. I wanted to add custom theme type to styled-components

I have theme folder with default.ts and default.d.ts files inside of it

*default.ts file:*

```js
import { DefaultTheme } from "styled-components";

const Theme: DefaultTheme = {
  fonts: {
    sans: "Inter",
  },
  borderRadius: "50px",
  colors: {
    main: "red",
    secondary: "blue",
  },
};

export default Theme;
```

*default.d.ts*

```js
// import original module declarations
import "styled-components";

// and extend them!
declare module "styled-components" {
  export interface DefaultTheme {
    fonts: {
      sans: string;
    };
    borderRadius: string;

    colors: {
      main: string;
      secondary: string;
    };
  }
}
```

but it is not working however if change `default.d.ts` to for example `styled.d.ts` or `defaultTheme.d.ts` it works fine

even `default.theme.d.ts` is not working

My question is

- is this a bug or something else